# Best strategy for Azure Search when source data changes

Tags: indexing, azure-cognitive-search

I was trying to find best strategy for Azure Search when source data changes on Azure Cognitive Search [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/search-documents), but in vain. Here is the scenario which bothers me:

1. User A uploads files, creates index, run indexers, when completed searches on his data set AA.
2. Meanwhile user B uploads his data, and he expect to get some results from his searches on data set BB.
3. In the same time user C wants to do search on whole new set AA+BB.

What should be done now: rebuild index or refresh? Is it necessary anyway or just to Run or Reset indexer? But if rebuild is in progress than no one can use Search.

On the other hand if there is Refresh in the progress than search results can be inconsistent, especially if BB set is big so it takes lot of time to refresh index.

Maybe using multiple indexes and then swap in between them, so that Search is not interrupted until indexing of new data is not finished completely.  Is there any best practices on this?

Comment: There are a few different aspects to your question -
1. Scoping search results to users - you can achieve this via filtering. Your source data needs to have a field that can use to scope results to particular users.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-filters

2. If you are using an indexer to build your index, have you looked at change detection policies to help your indexer pick up new items?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/create-data-source#data-change-detection-policies